# Laravel Inertia - Passing data Model->with hasMany relationship

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel 8 with InertiaJS Vue2. I'm trying to pass data with hasMany relationship to the vue for editing. How do I put the relationship in Edit.vue for form editing and posting?

```php
// Controller
class BooksController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $book = Books::where('id',$request->id)->with('locations')->firstOrFail();
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Books/Edit', ['book' => $book]);
    }
}
```

```php
// books model
class Books extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BookLocation::class);
    }
}
```

```js
// Edit.vue
<template>
    ...
    <div v-for="location in book.locations">
        <div>
            <jet-label for="location" value="Location" />
            <jet-input name="location" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" v-model="???"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

...

<script>
data() {
    return {
        form: this.$inertia.form({
            locations: this.book.locations???
        })
    }
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the relationship manually with Eloquent Collections Load Method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-load.

For your case

```
// Controller
class BooksController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $book = Books::where('id',$request->id)->with('locations')->firstOrFail();
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Books/Edit', ['book' => $book->load('locations')]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Saw Giek Zhen's answer is correct, there is also another way to go about it

On the model who has the relation, in this case the `Books` you can add an attribute which will automatically include this relation in all requests

```
// books model
class Books extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BookLocation::class);
    }

    protected $with = ['locations'];
}
```

this is called [eager loading by default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default)

you will then always have access to the `locations` as

```
<script>
data() {
    return {
        form: this.$inertia.form({
            locations: this.book.locations
        })
    }
},
</script>
```

also to get books ***without*** locations you can use the `without` function ;)

```
// Controller
class BooksController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $book = Books::where('id',$request->id)->with('locations')->firstOrFail();
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Books/Edit', ['book' => $book]);
    }

    public function showWithoutLocations(Request $request)
    {
        $book = Books::where('id',$request->id)->without('locations')->firstOrFail();
        return Inertia::render('Admin/Books/Edit', ['book' => $book]);
    }
}
```